# Dockerized lambda : Invoking sam local invoke returns an Unable to import module 'index': Dockerized

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, docker-compose, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

I am using AWS SAM and dockerized the lambdas. Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add bash && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual build-deps build-base gcc && \
    pip install aws-sam-cli && \
    apk del build-deps

WORKDIR /app/

RUN ls
COPY bin/sam_entrypoint.sh bin/

COPY lambda/hello_world/requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT "bin/sam_entrypoint.sh"
```

And Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  sam_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ["$PWD"]
    image: sam:0.1
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Here is my app structure.
[image]

And here is my `bin/sam_entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex
echo "Hello"
BASEDIR="${PWD}/lambda/"

/usr/local/bin/sam build \
--template lambda/template.yaml

/usr/local/bin/sam local start-api \
  --template lambda/template.yaml \
  --host 0.0.0.0 \
  --port 8000 \
  --docker-volume-basedir "${BASEDIR}" \
  --docker-network sam-app_default \
  --skip-pull-image
```

when I run `dc up` (starts api in local) and hit `http://0.0.0.0:8000/hello`. I got the following error. [image]

It seems like mounting is correct, but not sure what exactly i am doing wrong. It got to be something simple missing. I would appreciate any suggestions or help.

**EDIT**: Adding `template.yaml`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-app

  Sample SAM Template for sam-app
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
```

Comment: can you share `template.yaml` file ?

Comment: `template.yaml` is in `tests` folder? please check `path` to `template.yaml` in `lambda/` folder ?

Comment: no it is in lambda/.

Comment: ah, please zip `hello_world` folder instead of folder itself

Comment: sorry didn't get you exactly.

Comment: index file is not on the root. place index file in the root of zip

Comment: tried that. Moved index file under lambda & also to the root of the app. Getting same Same error.

Comment: I meant you have to compress `hello_world` to `hello_world.zip` file

Comment: okay, but I am not uploading to s3 yet. I just want to emulate lambda behavior in local using sam in docker environment.